# sporadic routing to another website when opening a common url

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, redirect

I have a strange problem in our office:

Sometimes when opening a <s>url from one of our projects</s> **random** url in any browser not the right website shows up but some other website.

In most of the cases it redirects to google.com with some parameters like https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=krOOU8_kGcSKswadyYDQBw&gws_rd=ssl or just the ugly google 404 page). But today it remains on the origial url but shows up the the content of http://debug.netdna-cdn.com/.

This happens about 1 time a week and for no apparent reason. <s>Even stranger it only occurs on a single pc in the network.</s> It now happens on two different computers in the network. Both use windows 8.

The problem cannot be fixed by clearing the browser cache but by rebooting the pc or using `ipconfig /flushdns`. So I think it has something to do with the dns cache of the machine. But I have no idea what the reason is for this and how i can figure out how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: We tried an external DNS Server (Googles 8.8.8.8) but the error still occures sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the pc uses the same Name Servers as do the user computers.
Instead of rebooting, just do as an administrator:

```
 ipconfig /flushdns
```

In the browser, also check that it does not make use of some kind of protection against phishing attacks offered by Google - that may be the cause for the original redirects.

Comment: yes, the ipconfig /flushdns solution works - but of course just temporarily. I need a permanent solution because it's very disturbing. There are no special phishing protection mechanism in our network.